# Google Maps v3 DistanceMatrix/Directions ignore avoidTolls:false

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to find the shortest route from **Lone Pine, CA** to **Yosemite Village, CA**.

A simple Google Maps lookup reveals two routes:

1. Toll routes: US-395N, CA-120W **~316 km**
2. No toll routes: CA-99N **~596 km**

DirectionService/DistanceMatrixService have an avoidTolls parameter:

```
avoidTolls (optional) — If true, the directions between points will be calculated using non-toll routes, wherever possible.
avoidTolls (optional) when set to true indicates that the calculated route(s) should avoid toll roads, if possible.
```

I expect the services to return route #1 when applying **`avoidTolls: false`**, but instead route #2 is returned.

Is my expectation or my implementation http://jsfiddle.net/nQzD8/2 flawed?

**Update:**

As **Dr. Molle** pointed out, route #1 is ignored not because of the toll routes included but because it might be closed at the current time ("This road may be seasonally closed." in the directions step).

**user2961817** found out, that the 316km result can be obtained by avoiding Highways (setting `avoidHighways: true`).

Are there other options to retrieve a DistanceMatrix result for another time of the year besides becoming a Maps for Business customer and use the DistanceMatrix API with the `departure_time` parameter?

**Solution:**

Route #1 is ignored because it might be closed at the time of the request and not because there are toll routes included. In order to retrieve the shorter route there are the following options:

***DistanceMatrixService:***

- Become a Business customer and set the departure_time parameter.
- Issue a 2nd request with `avoidHighways: true` and take the shorter
  route (*happens to work in this particular case but won't in most
  other cases*)

***DirectionService:***

- Use `provideRouteAlternatives:true`, iterate through alternatives and
  take the shortest one

Comment: It only returns the shorter route for me when provideRouteALternatives is true and avoidTolls is false. http://jsfiddle.net/nQzD8/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I explicitly draw a direction via `CA-120 W` I get the following information for this road: **This road may be seasonally closed** . Maybe that's the reason why google avoids this road.

[**The Tioga Road closes due to snow, usually from sometime in November through late May or early June.**](http://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/wroads.htm) ...it's november

Comment: Might be it. Where do you see the "seasonally closed" information? When I select US-395N/CA-120W as an alternative route I only get "This route has tolls.", nothing about seasons.

Comment: When I use the panel to get the text for the route I see for step#6: **Turn left onto CA-120 W/Tioga Rd
Continue to follow CA-120 W
Partial toll road
This road may be seasonally closed**

Comment: Any other options to retrieve a DistanceMatrix result for a specific month besides becoming a Maps for Business customer and use the DistanceMatrix API with the departure_time parameter?

Comment: AFAIK the departure_time-parameter is only available in directions and only when used with TRANSIT-mode. The only option I see is to request the directions with `provideRouteAlternatives:true` , parse each route and select the shortest route/duration

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me. When set to true it displays a different route then when set to false.

Expected result: 316 km via US-395 N and CA-120 W

Comment: Interesting. I get 596km for avoidTools:false and avoidTools:true. What distances do you get? Can you check http://jsfiddle.net/nQzD8/6/ it shows two identical routes to me.

Comment: When set to true: Distance via Distance Matrix:596 km
Distance via Direction Service:595 km
Expected result: 316 km via US-395 N and CA-120 W

Comment: When set to false: Distance via Distance Matrix:596 km
Distance via Direction Service:316 km
Expected result: 316 km via US-395 N and CA-120 W plus it displays a different route.

Comment: Can you post the specific revision that lets you retrieve 316km as the Direction result? All show 596km for me so far with avoidTolls: false.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/8px6ob7l1/ Not sure what you mean with revision, where can i find that?

Comment: This is very interesting: You got the 316 km result by avoiding highways. (avoidHighways: true)

Comment: Oh wait. since i am on a netbook, i accidently set avoidHighways to true. Which makes it display like in the screenshot. With avoidHighways set to false, setting avoidTolls to true or false displays the same route.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually helping me. I'll do both queries (avoidHighways true and false) and take the shorter one, in case there is no option for me to specify the date of departure unless I'm a Business customer.