# Google maps API: ignore seasonal restrictions in DirectionService request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I am currently developing a map where the shortest route between two points is shown (using different transports). I have noticed that sometimes, roads that are for example closed in the winter, are not taken into consideration.

I have found that I can ignore highways, tolls and ferries using the directionsservice (code below), but I can't for the life of me figure out how/if I can ignore seasonal restrictions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var request = {
    origin: _marker_from,
    destination: _marker_to,    
    travelMode: _mode,
    avoidFerries: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
    //avoidTimedConditions: true <-- I would need something like this
};

_service.route(request, function (response, status) {
    //More code here, not relevant for this question
}
```

Comment: If you vote to close and downvote me, at least have the decency to tell me what is wrong with my question :)

Comment: Good question. I’m interested if this is possible.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps v3 DistanceMatrix/Directions ignore avoidTolls:false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819586/google-maps-v3-distancematrix-directions-ignore-avoidtollsfalse)

Comment: I believe there is no easy way to ignore temporary closures. You can try setting departure time to the timestamp when the road should be open as a workaround.

Comment: @geocodezip: Just providing all the info I can give :) I just tried the provideRouteAlternatives:true-approach suggested in your post, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @xomena, setting departure times is only for premium business clients, as far as I can tell, and I am unfortunately not one of those. Plus, I want to make the website as dynamic as possible, because certain roads are closed at different times, But I think I'll have to accept that what I want is not possible.

Comment: @Michiel Standaert Departure time is available in Standard plan as well if you use a valid API key. According to the documentation `This option is only available if the **request contains a valid API key**, or a valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature. The departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the future. It cannot be in the past.` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **departureTime** in the **drivingOptions** of the directions request. Setting it to some point in time next summer should do the trick:

```
let now = new Date();

var request = {
    origin: _marker_from,
    destination: _marker_to,    
    travelMode: _mode,
    avoidFerries: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
    drivingOptions: {
        departureTime: new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1 + '/07/30'),
    }
};
```