# How to avoid seasonal roads while getting routes through google map API?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using google map API to show roads for cycling .I need a solution to get routes except seasonal roads. Can anyone help me

Comment: See if this workaround helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66743119/6513921

Comment: @MichaelD would this work for other tavelModes except Driving

Comment: I unfortunately haven't any familiarity with Google Map API. I hoped the workaround would provide some insights to you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.